# Bootstrap Tabs With SammyJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a better way to implement bootstrap tabs routing with SammyJS besides this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="lib/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/sammy-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Tab Example with Sammy.js</h2>
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab #3</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab #4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
<h4>Tab #1 Content</h4>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<h4>Tab #2 Content</h4>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
<h4>Tab #3 Content</h4>
<p>Nunc tempus felis vitae urna. Vivamus porttitor, neque at volutpat rutrum, purus nisi eleifend libero, a tempus libero lectus feugiat felis. Morbi diam mauris, viverra in, gravida eu, mattis in, ante. Morbi eget arcu. Morbi porta, libero id ullamcorper nonummy, nibh ligula pulvinar metus, eget consectetuer augue nisi quis lacus. Ut ac mi quis lacus mollis aliquam. Curabitur iaculis tempus eros. Curabitur vel mi sit amet magna malesuada ultrices. Ut nisi erat, fermentum vel, congue id, euismod in, elit. Fusce ultricies, orci ac feugiat suscipit, leo massa sodales velit, et scelerisque mi tortor at ipsum. Proin orci odio, commodo ac, gravida non, tristique vel, tellus. Pellentesque nibh libero, ultricies eu, sagittis non, mollis sed, justo. Praesent metus ipsum, pulvinar pulvinar, porta id, fringilla at, est.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
<h4>Tab #4 Content</h4>
<p>Maecenas aliquet velit vel turpis. Mauris neque metus, malesuada nec, ultricies sit amet, porttitor mattis, enim. In massa libero, interdum nec, interdum vel, blandit sed, nulla. In ullamcorper, est eget tempor cursus, neque mi consectetuer mi, a ultricies massa est sed nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Proin nulla arcu, nonummy luctus, dictum eget, fermentum et, lorem. Nunc porta convallis pede.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Update the URL with the current tabs hash
$("#myTabs a").click(function () { location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });
function ShowTab(tabname) {
//Show the selected tab
$('#myTabs a[href="#' + tabname + '"]').tab('show');
}
// Client-side routes
Sammy(function () {
this.get('#:selectedtab', function () {
ShowTab(this.params.selectedtab);
});
//default to the first tab if there is no hash in the URL
this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#tab1') });
}).run();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://github.com/christinekirsten/BootstrapTabsWithSammyJs/tree/9356810a9bb1f7538d806187a3fb511e0c417d34) is the link to the GitHub repo.